# In Netty can you read a ChannelBuffer twice in 3.x?

Tags: netty

Can you re-read a ChannelBuffer in Netty 3.x ? Meaning, can you create two separate ChannelBufferInputStreams using the same ChannelBuffer object and read with no additional marking/resetting necessary? Are you always guaranteed this will work, or only if backed by a certain type of source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you create separate views over the original buffer, there should be no problem:

```
ChannelBuffer original = ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer("xyzzy"
        .getBytes());

InputStream x = new ChannelBufferInputStream(original.duplicate());
InputStream y = new ChannelBufferInputStream(original.duplicate());
```

Here, you can read idependently from x and y without affecting the indexes of the original buffer.